# Scala - How to safely operate on a map element

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I want to get an element from a mutable map and do an operation on it.
For example I want to change his name value (the element on the map will be with the new value)
and I want to return it in the end

to start I wrote a working code but it is very Java

```
var newAppKey: AppKey = null

val appKey = myMap(request.appKeyId)
if (appKey != null) {
  newAppKey = appKey.copy(name = request.appKeyName)
  myMap.put(appKey.name, newAppKey)
  newAppKey
} else {
  newAppKey = null
}
```

This code works but it very java.

I though about something like

```
val newAppKey = appIdToApp(request.appKeyId) match {
  case: Some(appKey) => appKey.copy(name = request.appKeyName)
  case: None => None{AppKey}
}
```

Which doesn't compile or updates the myMap object with the new value.

How do I improve it to scala concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
val key = request.appKeyId
val newValueOpt = myMap.get(key).map(_.copy(name = request.appKeyName))
newValueOpt.foreach(myMap.update(key, _))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code.

> case: Some(appKey) => appKey.copy(name = request.appKeyName)

This syntax for case is incorrect. It should be

```
case Some(appKey) => appKey.copy(name = request.appKeyName)
```

Also, the return type of your expression is currently `Any` (Scala equivalent of Object), because your success case returns an object of type (appKey's type) whereas the failure case returns a `None`, which is of type `Option`. To make things consistent, your success case should return

```
Some(appKey.copy(name = request.appKeyName))
```

While there are better ways to deal with Options than pattern matching, the corrected code would be

```
val newAppKey = appIdToApp(request.appKeyId) map (appKey => 
  appKey.copy(name = request.appKeyName))
```

Comment: Thanks, This breaks compilation with "expression of type AppKey" doesn't conform to expected type Null

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that that bit was wrong as well. I think you want the entire expression to return an `Option` of type `AppKey`, is that right? If so, I'll change my answer so it's even simpler, using `map`.